# Problems starting to use Launchpad

Tags: application-development, launchpad, bazaar

I've been reading the different tutorials that Launchpad directs you to. And they've all helped alot. And seems like the system is a lot simpler and easier to use than Github. But I can't seem to get my first code up into project.

I followed this tutorial > [Push Bazaar Branch](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/UploadingABranch/)

But when I type the first command, I get back this:

> WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-g5JhUc/pkcs11: No such file or directory

I've already made my ssh keys and registered it with Launchpad. And tried both with and without optional config file. I still get back the same exact thing. :( I understand that these tools need to be powerful for developers. Just wish it didn't have to be so difficult.

**Edit** oh and as a side note, can I upload Illumination Software Creator files? Or a tar.gz file of all the artwork in my project?

**Second Edit** I just now tried another command found on the Launchpad page for uploading code to a branch

> bzr push lp:~clem11388/pictureadventure/trunk

But I get this back

> bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/daniel/My Projects/".

So could the problem be that I don't know what a "Branch" is? Much less how to create one? I'm going to be trying to enter this app / game into the App Showdown. So I really need to get all this figured out soon.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you can upload anything you want to Launchpad. The `bzr` tool doesn't care what is in it, but it handles textual content best (e.g. any source code) but it can also upload images, audio, video and more.

When you create a new directory for a project and you want it to be a bzr branch, be sure to initialize it so bzr can track it in with version control (if you are using Quickly to create your app, it already did this for you).

To initialize it run:

```
cd <your project directory>
bzr init
```

If you are pushing to `bzr push lp:~clem11388/pictureadventure/trunk` it also presumes http://launchpad.net/pictureadventure exists (which it looks like it does).

Comment: Awesome, Thank you sir!! I'm getting ready to run that command right now. But then how do I choose exactly which file I want to upload? Sorry, I'm extremely new at this, I tried watching the different videos I found on the developer.ubuntu.com. But they didn't seem to cover these indepth details. **Edit** P.S. I seen your video on Quickly, and it was really informative on Python and the Quickly program. But I'm using Illumination Software Creator cause it require zero coding experience. Even for a web browser. Not always as attractive looking. But a really good start. :-)

Comment: You need to tell Bazaar to add files to the project with `bzr add file1 file2 ...` and then commit this change (adding of files) with `bzr commit`, and then do the `bzr push` to upload to launchpad. Have you read the 5-minute tutorial? http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/mini-tutorial/index.html